# Sleep(10) does nothing?

Tags: .net, multithreading, web-services, remote-desktop

I have a strange situation with my web service.

It is a simple one - it creates a Thread that runs constantly, doing some disk checks in the background, and for every File.Exists that it performs, it goes into Sleep(10) so it doesn't consume ALL of the CPU core.

It all works well, until I log of from RDP.  When I do that, this thread will spike and consume as much as it can.

Here, have a look-see...

I have two cores, and my foreground app is using about 18% CPU (whis is shown on the NOW-meter).  To the left is the CPU usage when no-one is logged on.

What is going on?  And more - what to do to throttle the Thread appropriately under this circumstance?

[image]

My code snippet that produces the issue:

```
foreach (string fi in files)
{
    if (_shouldStop)
    {
        break;
    }
    lock (_workItems)
    {
        StatusString = string.Format("Examining file Dir={0}\nmask={1}\nfile={2}\nqueue={3}",
            root, mask, fi, _workItems.Count);
    }
    lock (_workItems)
    {
        if (!_workItems.Contains(fi))
        {
            if (!File.Exists(TargetForFile(fi + ".hash")))
            {
                StatusString = string.Format("Adding file Dir={0}\nmask={1}\nfile={2}\nqueue={3}",
                root, mask, fi, _workItems.Count);
                _workItems.Add(fi);
            }
        }
    }
    Thread.Sleep(10);
}
```

Small update:

Even `Sleep(1000)` does NOTHING when code is run as windows service and no-one is connected to the machine.  I officially declare it a WTF.

Comment: Sure it's not RDP? :) (E.g. what are results when RDP + no app + same monitoring?)

Comment: have you tried increasing the sleep time?

Comment: Does that graph update every millisecond?

Comment: Graph is from procexp, and it has 10 seconds update time.  When I get the sleep to 50, it works better, but I need 10, as 50 won't work for me (processing is TOOO slow then)

Comment: @pst: left - NO rdp, right, I logged on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sleep 10 is only 10 milliseconds -- so you are really close to just yielding and going back to work.

My guess would be that when you are logged on, there is enough going on that your thread doesn't get rescheduled immediately, so that it really ends up being inactive for more than 10 milliseconds (and I think I read that the max resolution of the sleep is 100 mills, btw).  However, when you are not RDP'd, the thread becomes available for rescheduling far more frequently, so it burns more CPU.

To test, try increasing your sleep duration to 500 (0.5 sec), or 1000, or so, to give you a noticeable sleep period.

Another test, would be to throw down another thread in a do-nothing loop and see if your file.exists thread yields respectfully when you are forcing the CPU to be busy.

Comment: yes, but yielding is OK for me, and it does nice when there is GUI attached.  when there is no GUI, yielding does, as it seems, nothing?  however, I can do 10 steps, then sleep(100), and that might solve my problems.  thanks for the idea, and for the intuitive insight!

Comment: You're doing disk io. That's slow! You don't need the sleep.

Comment: @JohnSaunders trust me, I do.  I do only File.Exists, and since I am shuffling same directories over and over again, everything is in the cache, and I end up gobbling all the CPU...

Comment: You know, they put schedulers in the OS for this purpose. You really don't need the Sleep. Let the OS do its job.

Comment: @JohnSaunders again, I can give you the code to test it yourself - I tried that and ended up with NO reasonable results, expecting the same from the starting point that you suggest.

Comment: I added the code, realizing that I lied a little - I go to disk only when I don't have the item in the queue already - so I have to Sleep() anyway.

Comment: @DanielMošmondor: no, you don't have to sleep. Take it from the experts.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5703/discussion-between-daniel-mosmondor-and-john-saunders)

Answer (score 5):

Don't sleep. Set your thread priority to IDLE instead.

Next thing is to identify the CPU consumption *per process*, so you don't chase a red herring. Open the Perfmom.exe and look at the [`Process(*)\(*)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms804621.aspx) object (all instances). Then you can inspect the `% Processor Time` and `% User Time` *for each process* and identify who is using the 18% when RDP is closed.

As a side note, rather than `shuffling same directories over and over again`, why not use the [change notifications mechanism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead?

Comment: 18% is ok, it is the process that needs that 18%, and it's OK.  Also, I can't examine proces cpu usage, because what I am presenting here as an issue is a thread inside the w3svc app pool.

Comment: as for the change notifications, I heard so much about it and nothing was ever with the happy-end, tried it myself and was burned...  So I stick with polling from that point in time...

Comment: Sure you can examine process CPU usage. Your w3svc app pool is a process. I'm not saying 18% is bad (well, if you app uses 18% *just to monitor changes*, it actually **is** bad), I want you to confirm that the 18% comes from you app indeed.

Comment: no, ONE app is monitoring changes, and I don't want to see it's percentage on the CPU usage chart.  Other app, which is doing something useful, consumes 18%

Answer (score 2):

get spikes like that when I log onto RDP, and I don't have your code running. Occam's razor would suggest it's RDP that's making use of the cores.

Besides, if you're doing File.Exists, the thread's going to be blocking on disk I/O anyway, if there's a point where it's putting a serious burden on the CPU, it won't be when it's just done that.

Finally, if you haven't done anything nuts like up the process priority from Normal, then it's going to share the cores with other processes anyway. It might be a bit bad if it falls into a tight loop, but even then the scheduler should prevent it doing too much harm on its own. All the more so with the more recent versions of Windows, and if you have more than one core.

Edit: Actually, scratch all that. Why poll in a loop yourself rather than in response to a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) event. Set one or more `FileSystemWatcher`s to watch directory(s) of interest, and then poll for the specific file existence changes you care about in response to that. Less work for the code, and should be more responsive too.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the answers provided, but I'll try to provide one of my own.

I don't need architecture change at this point, and any attempts to use any amount of `Sleep()` failed.  I searched a little other sites besides SO, and found one thread in which Jon Skeet suggests usage of `Monitor` to signal around.

This inspired me to try and change the `Sleep` to `WaitOne` of `AutoResetEvent`, which I'll use only as alternative to sleeping which, as it seems, doesn't work under my circumstances.

Tried it, and it worked!